# NewtonSoft Json.NET and Single Element Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I have some JSon that I am converting to an object using the ToObject method.

A part of this Json has a repeated element which is correctly represented as an array in the Json text.  When I convert this it correctly is mapped to the C# object

```
public IList<FooData> Foo { get; set; }
```

But when I only have 1 element I get an error saying that the Json that I am trying to Parse into an object is not an array because it does not have `[]` around it.

Does Json.NET support single element arrays?

Comment: Single element array in JSON still have `[]` around the element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n)

Comment: If it doesn't have `[]` it isn't a valid JSON array, so the message is correct. What's generating the JSON your trying to parse? I'd suggest that, that code is wrong, not Json.Net

Comment: There is a very similar question and a good solution for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when I only have 1 element I get an error saying that the Json
>   that I am trying to Parse into an object is not an array because it
>   does not have [] around it.

If a JSON text has no `[]` around, then it's not a *single-element array*: actually it's **an object** (for example: `{ "text": "hello world" }`).

Try using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method:

```
jsonText = jsonText.Trim();

// If your JSON string starts with [, it's an array...
if(jsonText.StartsWith("["))
{
    var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<string>>(jsonText);
}
else // Otherwise, it's an object...
{
    var someObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(jsonText);
}
```

It can also happen that JSON text contains a literal value like `1` or `"hello world"`... but I believe that these are very edge cases...

For the above edge cases just deserialize them with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(jsonText)` for example (replace `string` with `int` or whatever...).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are enclosing your JSON single item array is still specified as an array using array notation `[]`